# Perl Command to find Sequence Match

Tags: perl, match, sequence

Could anyone explain me how exactly this perl line is build up and how it works?

```
perl -lane'if ($_ =~ "sequence xy") {@arr=split("right part of sequence xy"); print $arr[1]}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think *works* might be overselling it. It is not a very well written piece of code.

- `-l` is end-of-line handling. It sets `$/` and `$\` to `\n`, and chomps lines from input. Basically a convenience to handle newlines.
- `-a` is autosplit, it will split each line of input into an array `@F`. By default it splits on whitespace. Sadly, this is unused in this particular code and could be safely removed.
- `-n` assumes a `while (<>)` loop around the code. This basically reads input from files or stdin, and executes the code inside for each line.

As for the code, `if ($_ =~ "sequence xy")`, should be written `if (/sequence xy/)`, since the `$_` is implied, and this is a common Perl idiom. Second, the binding operator `=~` should be followed by a search pattern, substitution, or transliteration (`m//`, `s///`, `tr//`). See [perldoc perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Binding-Operators). In this case it will just assume that the string is a regex pattern and use the match operator `m//`. This checks if the current line from the input matches the string `sequence xy`.

If the match happens, the line in split. Again, [`split`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split) should contain a match operator, not a string. The documentation says `split /PATTERN/, EXPR, LIMIT` where the 2 last are optional, and it will use `$_` if it lacks EXPR. Normally split would be used like this: `@arr = split /,/, $foo` (this will split a string inside variable `$foo` on comma). This will use the sentence `right part of sequence xy` to split. Then it will print the second element in the resulting list. So if you had

```
Fooo bar baz right part of sequence xy hello world
```

It would print `hello world`.

All the lines of the input or file that do not contain `sequence xy` will be ignored.

This can be improved to:

```
perl -lne'if (/sequence xy/) { print( (split /right part of sequence xy/)[1] ) }'
```

You can also write this code more verbosely and put it in a file, and execute it as a command: `perl foo.pl inputfile.txt`, `othercommand | perl foo.pl`, or `./foo.pl input.txt`. You would then use something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;         # always use these
 
while (<>) {          # reading input from file or stdin
    if (/sequence xy/) {  # for lines matching this...
        chomp;            # remove newline
        my ($left, $right) = split /right part of sequence xy/;
                             # don't need an array to print one value
        print "$right\n";    # instead of -l print with a newline
    }
}
```